# Split pandas dataframe into chunks of N

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm currently trying to split a pandas dataframe into an unknown number of chunks containing each N rows.

I have tried using numpy.array_split() this funktion however splits the dataframe into N chunks containing an unknown number of rows.

Is there a clever way to split a python dataframe into multiple dataframes, each containing a specific number of rows from the parent dataframe

Comment: what if the lenght of df is not divisble by N?

Comment: it's ok if the first or last chunk have more entries, but no less

Comment: what if you have less than N rows ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def rolling(df, window, step):
    count = 0
    df_length = len(df)
    while count < (df_length -window):
        yield count, df[count:window+count]
        count += step
```

Usage:

```
for offset, window in rolling(df, 100, 100):
    # |     |                      |     |
    # |     The current chunk.     |     How many rows to step at a time.
    # The current offset index.    How many rows in each chunk.
    # your code here
    pass
```

There is also this simpler idea:

```
def chunk(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
```

Usage:

```
for df_chunk in chunk(df, 100):
    #                     |
    #                     The chunk size
    # your code here
```

BTW. All this can be found on SO, with a search.

Answer (score 2):

calculate the index of splits :

```
size_of_chunks =  3
index_for_chunks = list(range(0, index.max(), size_of_chunks))
index_for_chunks.extend([index.max()+1])
```

use them to split the df :

```
dfs = {}
for i in range(len(index_for_chunks)-1):
    dfs[i] = df.iloc[index_for_chunks[i]:index_for_chunks[i+1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the number of splits from N:

```
splits = int(np.floor(len(df.index)/N))
chunks = np.split(df.iloc[:splits*N], splits)
chunks.append(df.iloc[splits*N:])
```