# Get indexes of Pandas Rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I would like to get the indexes of the elements in each rolling window of a Pandas Series.

A solution that works for me is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704557/15024002) answer to an existing question: I get the `window.index` for each `window` obtained from the `rolling` function described in the answer. I am only interested in `step=1` for the aforementioned function.

But this function is not specific for DataFrames and Series, it would work on basic Python lists.
Isn't there some functionality that takes advantage of Pandas rolling operations?

I tried the `Rolling.apply` method:

```py
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

rolling = s.rolling(window=3)
indexes = rolling.apply(lambda x: x.index)
```

But it result in a `TypeError: must be real number, not RangeIndex`. Apparently, the `Rolling.apply` method only accepts functions that return a number based on each window. The functions cannot return other kinds of objects.

Are there other methods of the Pandas `Rolling` class I could use? Even private methods.

Or are there any other Pandas-specific functionalities to get the indexes of overlapping rolling windows?

#### Expected output

As output, I expect some kind of list-of-lists object. Each inner list should countain the index values of each window.
The original `s` Series  has `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` as index.
So, rolling with a `window=3`, I expect as outcome something like:

```py
[
    [0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [4, 5, 6],
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `apply` function after `rolling` must return a numeric value for each window. One possible workaround is to use a list comprehension to iterate over each window and apply the custom transformation as required:

```
[[*l.index] for l in s.rolling(3) if len(l) == 3]
```

Alternatively you can also use `sliding_window_view` to accomplish the same:

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(s.index, 3)
```

Or even an list comprehension would do the job just fine:

```
w = 3
[[*s.index[i : i + w]] for i in range(len(s) - w + 1)]
```

Result

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works just fine for me!
For my purposes, I do not really need that the inner lists are actually lists: that was just for an example for the expected output. For my purposes, the inner object can be a Pandas Index. So, I simply use: `[l.index for l in s.rolling(3) if len(l) == 3]`.

Comment: pandas rolling object also has a min_periods parameter. How would you code it in the case of `np.lib.stride_strics.sliding_window_view`?