# How to iterate over equal row chunks in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that records a battery's discharge amount and temperature every hour. The first 10 hour of each day (starting at 13:00:00) is discharge period, and the next 14 hours are charge period.

My goal is to calculate the sum Energy column for the first 10 hours of each day (EnergySum) and set the sum to 26 if it exceeds 26 (since it shows decrease from battery's full capacity). Afterwards, I create another variable based on this amount, that shows battery's current capacity level (Cap).

Then, I want to add a column (named as Charged) to df, set the first 10 rows for each day to zero, and for the next 14 hours, I want to read from Capacity, and add the capacity amount to the current capacity level. Charged column records the amount added to current capacity. There will be a row that exceeds the maximum capacity. For that row, I want to record the fraction required to reach full capacity. For the next rows, Charged value will be zero.

After this is done, a column named as Consumption will be made that does the same thing as Charged, but reads from Electricity column instead.

Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
data = {'Date/Time':
 ['04/09  13:00:00','04/09  14:00:00','04/09  15:00:00','04/09  16:00:00','04/09  17:00:00','04/09  18:00:00','04/09  19:00:00','04/09  20:00:00','04/09  21:00:00','04/09  22:00:00','04/09  23:00:00','04/09  24:00:00',  '04/10  01:00:00','04/10  02:00:00','04/10  03:00:00','04/10  04:00:00','04/10  05:00:00','04/10  06:00:00','04/10  07:00:00','04/10  08:00:00','04/10  09:00:00','04/10  10:00:00','04/10  11:00:00','04/10  12:00:00'],
'Energy':
[1.129094859,1.678736662,1.936771353,1.815096405,1.449398946,0.785971775,0.234247622,0.003275094,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
'Temperature':
[25,26,26,26,26,25,24,24,23,22,22,21,21,20,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,21,21],
'Capacity':
[2.1,2,2,2,2,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.1,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2],
'Electricity':
[0.84,0.85,0.85,0.85,0.85,0.84,0.83,0.83,0.82,0.81,0.81,0.8,0.8,0.79,0.78,0.78,0.78,0.78,0.78,0.79,0.79,0.79,0.8,0.8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I managed to get the desired results for the first 24 hours using the code below. I used the help [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/) (Method #2) for this.

```
EnergySum = df.Energy.iloc[0:10].sum()      # Sum of battery discharge in the discharge period
if EnergySum > 26:                          # Stop recording when battery is fully depleted
    EnergySum = 26

Cap = 26 - EnergySum                        # The battery's current capacity level

for row in range(len(df[0:24:])):
    if row < 10 and row >= 0:               # Battery won't be charged in discharge period, so
        df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = 0          # the amounts for that period will be set to zero
    else:
        if 26 - Cap > df.loc[row, 'Capacity']:  # For when maximum capacity is not reached
            df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = df.loc[row, 'Capacity']
            Cap = Cap + df.Charged[row]
            print('Cap After:', Cap)
        elif 26 - Cap < df.loc[row, 'Capacity']: # For the row that exceeds maximum capacity
            print('Cap Before:', Cap)
            Residual = Cap - 26
            df.loc[row, 'Charged'] =  - Residual
            Cap = 26
        else:                                    # For rows after when maximum capacity is reached
            df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = 0
            
    df.loc[row, 'Consumption'] = (df.loc[row, 'Charged']/df.loc[row, 'Capacity'])*df.loc[row, 'Electricity']  # Adding Consumption column
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
Date/Time   Energy  Temperature Capacity    Electricity Charged Consumption
0   04/09 13:00:00  1.129095    25  2.1 0.84    0.000000    0.000000
1   04/09 14:00:00  1.678737    26  2.0 0.85    0.000000    0.000000
2   04/09 15:00:00  1.936771    26  2.0 0.85    0.000000    0.000000
3   04/09 16:00:00  1.815096    26  2.0 0.85    0.000000    0.000000
4   04/09 17:00:00  1.449399    26  2.0 0.85    0.000000    0.000000
5   04/09 18:00:00  0.785972    25  2.1 0.84    0.000000    0.000000
6   04/09 19:00:00  0.234248    24  2.1 0.83    0.000000    0.000000
7   04/09 20:00:00  0.003275    24  2.1 0.83    0.000000    0.000000
8   04/09 21:00:00  0.000000    23  2.1 0.82    0.000000    0.000000
9   04/09 22:00:00  0.000000    22  2.2 0.81    0.000000    0.000000
10  04/09 23:00:00  0.000000    22  2.2 0.81    2.200000    0.810000
11  04/09 24:00:00  0.000000    21  2.2 0.80    2.200000    0.800000
12  04/10 01:00:00  0.000000    21  2.2 0.80    2.200000    0.800000
13  04/10 02:00:00  0.000000    20  2.2 0.79    2.200000    0.790000
14  04/10 03:00:00  0.000000    19  2.2 0.78    0.232593    0.082465
15  04/10 04:00:00  0.000000    19  2.2 0.78    0.000000    0.000000
16  04/10 05:00:00  0.000000    19  2.2 0.78    0.000000    0.000000
17  04/10 06:00:00  0.000000    19  2.2 0.78    0.000000    0.000000
18  04/10 07:00:00  0.000000    19  2.2 0.78    0.000000    0.000000
19  04/10 08:00:00  0.000000    20  2.2 0.79    0.000000    0.000000
20  04/10 09:00:00  0.000000    20  2.2 0.79    0.000000    0.000000
21  04/10 10:00:00  0.000000    20  2.2 0.79    0.000000    0.000000
22  04/10 11:00:00  0.000000    21  2.2 0.80    0.000000    0.000000
23  04/10 12:00:00  0.000000    21  2.2 0.80    0.000000    0.000000
```

But I'm facing difficulties applying this code to the entire DataFrame. I used method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48704557/19745970) for splitting my rows into chunks of 24 and came up with this:

```
def chunk(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))


for df_chunk in chunk(df, 24):
    EnergySum = df.Energy.iloc[0:10].sum()
    if EnergySum > 26:
        EnergySum = 26
    Cap = 26 - EnergySum
    for row in range(len(df_chunk)):
        if row < 10 and row >= 0:
            df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = 0
        else:
            if 26 - Cap > df.loc[row, 'Capacity']:
                df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = df.loc[row, 'Capacity']
                Cap = Cap + df.Charged[row] 
            elif 26 - Cap < df.loc[row, 'Capacity']:
                Residual = Cap - 26
                df.loc[row, 'Charged'] =  - Residual
                Cap = 26
            else:
                df.loc[row, 'Charged'] = 0
        df.loc[row, 'Consumption'] = (df.loc[row, 'Charged']/df.loc[row, 'Capacity'])*df.loc[row, 'Electricity']
```

This code does not give me any errors, but when I check the results, I see that the results are all wrong. I'm assuming this is because variables EnergySum and Cap are defined inside the loop, but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: The desired output for the first 24 rows has been added.